# How to generate dev channel Windows 10 insider iso?

Tags: windows-10, iso-image, windows-insider

I know Microsoft provide a [website for downloading them](http://aka.ms/WIPISO) but the builds there aren’t up to date (by several public build numbers behind). For example, the current build number is [`21327`](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2021/03/03/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-21327/) and the [lastest available iso](http://aka.ms/WIPISO) is `21286`.

So how can I generate an iso from Microsoft update allowing me to start fresh installs with the latest version directly instead of having to install an older version first?

Comment: I’m talking about installing from Microsoft update, but about getting the latest version as an iso before it becomes downloadable as an iso.

Comment: You use the same method to create a custom windows image.  Which is not a complicated process but has several steps.  [There are third-party websites that do the hard work for you](https://uupdump.ml/).  The files in the example are all from Microsoft, it uses a script to patch the ISO, much easier to use something that already exists.

Comment: @Ramhound disagree a bit with such method. With such a method I’m getting all installed programs everywhere. I’m needing something without installing the build through Microsoft update.

Comment: There is also a method to apply the updates to the install.wim.  See the third-party [reference](https://uupdump.ml/) on how that is accomplished.  I will spoil it for you, it's done with DISM, I apologize for spoiling the reveal.  How it's accomplished is a little more involved than an answer will allow.  If you are stuck on a specific step we might be able to help.

Comment: @Ramhound which doesn t works as windows insider updates are downloaded using a different method requiring a Microsoft account. Such updates contains the folder structure of an install iso. The problem is I don t know how to download them to a folder nor how to extract them.

Comment: [Thankfully](https://www.uupdump.net/known.php?q=regex:[2-9]\d{4}\.) others have done the work for you.